# Calculating mean of a subset within a dataframe in r

Tags: r, csv, subset, mean

I'm new to R and struggling with calculating the mean of subsets.
I have 12 csv files in "datafolder".  The column names within each csv are "Order Date", "ID", "cupcake" and "muffin".  All values in the last 3 columns are numerical with the exception of some NA's.
I need to calculate the mean quantity of each type of cake for each ID (store number).
In the code below I've attempted to rbind all csv files into a dataframe.
I want to be able to call the mean value of each individual cake column so I've tried to subset "cupcake" and "muffin" so that I can find the mean value of the subset when I select ID or range of IDs.

```
 cakemean <- function(directory, cake, ID=1:12) {    
+                 files_list <- dir("datafolder", full.names = TRUE)     
+                 dat <- data.frame()      
+                 for (i in 1:12) {              
+                 dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))    }    
+                 dat_subset <- subset(dat, dat$ID == ID)     
+                 mean(dat_subset$cupcake, na.rm = TRUE)
+                 mean(dat_subset$muffin, na.rm = TRUE)
+               
+         }
>         cakemean("datafolder", "cupcake", 1)
[1] 0.5528041
> cakemean("datafolder", "muffin", 1)
[1] 0.5528041
> cakemean("datafolder", "cupcake", 1:5)
[1] 0.5528041
```

When I call "cakemean" I get a value returned that is not the mean value of the cake selected.  Whether I select "cupcake" or "muffin" I get the same value, and if I still get the same value if I don't select a cake and just select the ID.

I've been searching everywhere trying to get a solution to this however I seem to be having problems in general with mean calculations.  I have attempted colMeans and this has been less helpful than the above approach.  I need the function to be reusable as I'll probably need it later to calculate a mean or median value by order date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you want to read in all those csv files everytime you want to run this function? secondly, you should use `%in%` instead of `==`. and third,  you don't get differences with muffin or cupcake because the `cake` argument is not used within the function. I assume you would want to use something like `mean(dat_subset[cake])`

Comment: Intention is to create dataframe "dat" to contain all data following the rbind.  Sorry, this should be the reusable element once it's been created.

Comment: And thanks, I've replaced "==" with "%in%".  Will experiment with [cake].

Comment: There's so much wrong with that function it's hard to know where to start the corrective efforts. If you are passing a value to `directory` you shouldn't use the character value inside the function. If you are passing a vector of column numbers you should not be using `$` as axtraction function. No reference to the `cake` object in the function body. I think you should work with your tutors at whatever school you are taking classes. You should start small and build up from successful functions rather than packing everythin into  the final product.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've actually based it on a practice assignment supplied by a former student because they wanted to help others who also found that the course material didn't supplied enough information to put together this function.  As an online learner I don't have tutors to ask and am currently spending as many hours studying as I am on my full time job!  All my fellow students are having problems with this.  The queries used at the end of the code are from the unit tests that will be run against my function.  Not a great start clearly!